# How can I get github user-related issue data by rest api?

Tags: github-api

I want to use Github rest api to get the issue user-related events (see screenshot), just like `GET /users/:username/received_events` on https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/.

I have found `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:issue_number/events` on https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/ which is closed but is not what I want. Is there an api or a method to get such event data.

Tips: `GET /issues` or `GET /user/issues` is not a right one, because it is requiring user being assigned.

screenshots: [recent activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egtZP.png), [issue event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8gAr.png)

Comment: upload the images ,we don't encourage external links

Comment: I'm sorry but StackOverflow says: As soon as you earn 10 reputation on the site, you will be able to embed images. (I don't use stackoverflow to ask question infrequently)